# Maintaining data quality and speeding up query with two OR statements in JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am troubleshooting part of a VERY complex query that is performing very slowly.

As written, the query takes 40 minutes to execute and returns ~141,000 results. I am using SQL Server 2005 (yep).

The problematic part of the code is the multiple OR statements within the JOIN. Here's the original query. Keep in mind that the SELECT clause contains a ton of processing that I am not including for space reasons. The query subsequently joins to three more tables, but I am not including them since they are all simple joins.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.date_1 = t1.date
INNER JOIN table3 t3  on ( t3.sid = t1.sid )
LEFT JOIN table4 t4 ON
    ((t1.cid != 26 AND t4.srscid = t1.cid)  OR (t1.cid = 26 AND t1.pcode = t4.pcode) )
    AND (t1.sid = t4.section OR t1.sid = t4.r_section)
    and t1.nprice >= t4.min_breakpoint AND t1.nprice <= t4.max_breakpoint
    and t1.date >= t4.start AND t1.date <= t4.end
```

In an attempt to speed this up, referencing other advice I've seen here, I've converted the two OR statements to UNIONs.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.date_1 = t1.date
INNER JOIN table3 t3  on ( t3.sid = t1.sid )
LEFT JOIN table4 t4 ON
    ((t1.cid != 26 AND t4.srscid = t1.cid) )
    AND (t1.sid = t4.section OR t1.sid = t4.r_section)
    and t1.nprice >= t4.min_breakpoint AND t1.nprice <= t4.max_breakpoint
    and t1.date >= t4.start AND t1.date <= t4.end
UNION

SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.date_1 = t1.date
INNER JOIN table3 t3  on ( t3.sid = t1.sid )
LEFT JOIN table4 t4 ON
    ((t1.cid = 26 AND t1.pcode = t4.pcode) )
    AND (t1.sid = t4.section OR t1.sid = t4.r_section)
    and t1.nprice >= t4.min_breakpoint AND t1.nprice <= t4.max_breakpoint
    and t1.date >= t4.start AND t1.date <= t4.end
```

The above query did perform faster, executing in ~30 mins, but it returned 307,000 results.

The only difference I see between my case and the examples I've encountered elsewhere are that the OR statement occurs in a set of parentheses.

Can anyone help troubleshoot why the UNION is returning so many different results from the OR join?

Thanks.

Comment: The `UNION` is removing duplicates.  That would seem to be at least one obvious culprit.

Comment: But the `UNION` returns more results, not fewer.

Comment: Just ran a few tests. Running the first query with a `LEFT JOIN` and running the other with `INNER` returned >300,000 results again, but running both with an `INNER JOIN` returned 145,000 results. Much less than the 161,000 of the original query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the 2 queries have a left join to table4.
But with the criteria for cid 26 in the on clause.

To illustrate it, look at the output of these simplified examples:

> ```
> --
> -- sample data
> --
> create table tbl1 
> (
>     cid int primary key,
>     pcode varchar(30) not null
> );
>
> create table tbl2
> (
>     id2 int identity(1,1) primary key,
>     srscid int,
>     pcode varchar(30) not null
> );
>
> insert into tbl1 (cid, pcode) values
> (26, 'a'),
> (31, 'b'),(32, 'c'),(33, 'd');
>
> insert into tbl2 (pcode, srscid) values
> ('a', 26),('b', 26), 
> ('x', 31),('y', 32);
> ```

> ```
> -- query 1
> -- cid != 26, srscid = cid
> --
> select t1.*, t2.id2, t2.pcode as pcode2
> from tbl1 t1
> left join tbl2 t2
> on (t2.srscid = t1.cid and t1.cid != 26)
> ```
>
> ```
> cid | pcode |  id2 | pcode2
> --: | :---- | ---: | :-----
>  26 | a     | null | null  
>  31 | b     |    3 | x     
>  32 | c     |    4 | y     
>  33 | d     | null | null
> ```

> ```
> -- query 2
> -- cid = 26, pcode
> --
> select t1.*, t2.id2, t2.pcode as pcode2
> from tbl1 t1
> left join tbl2 t2
> on (t2.pcode = t1.pcode and t1.cid = 26)
> ```
>
> ```
> cid | pcode |  id2 | pcode2
> --: | :---- | ---: | :-----
>  26 | a     |    1 | a     
>  31 | b     | null | null  
>  32 | c     | null | null  
>  33 | d     | null | null
> ```

> ```
> -- query 3
> -- cid != 26 or cid = 26
> --
> select t1.*, t2.id2, t2.pcode as pcode2
> from tbl1 t1
> left join tbl2 t2
> on ((t2.srscid = t1.cid    and t1.cid != 26) or 
>     (t2.pcode = t1.pcode and t1.cid = 26))
> ```
>
> ```
> cid | pcode |  id2 | pcode2
> --: | :---- | ---: | :-----
>  26 | a     |    1 | a     
>  31 | b     |    3 | x     
>  32 | c     |    4 | y     
>  33 | d     | null | null
> ```

> ```
> -- query 4
> -- union query 1 & 2
> --
> select t1.*, t2.id2, t2.pcode as pcode2
> from tbl1 t1
> left join tbl2 t2
> on (t2.srscid = t1.cid and t1.cid != 26)
> UNION
> select t1.*, t2.id2, t2.pcode
> from tbl1 t1
> left join tbl2 t2
> on (t2.pcode = t1.pcode and t1.cid = 26)
> ```
>
> ```
> cid | pcode |  id2 | pcode2
> --: | :---- | ---: | :-----
>  26 | a     | null | null  
>  26 | a     |    1 | a     
>  31 | b     | null | null  
>  31 | b     |    3 | x     
>  32 | c     | null | null  
>  32 | c     |    4 | y     
>  33 | d     | null | null
> ```

> ```
> -- query 4
> -- union ALL, with WHERE clauses
> --
> select t1.*, t2.id2, t2.pcode as pcode2
> from tbl1 t1
> left join tbl2 t2
> on t2.srscid = t1.cid 
> WHERE t1.cid != 26
> UNION ALL
> select t1.*, t2.id2, t2.pcode
> from tbl1 t1
> left join tbl2 t2
> on t2.pcode = t1.pcode 
> WHERE t1.cid = 26
> order by t1.cid
> ```
>
> ```
> cid | pcode |  id2 | pcode2
> --: | :---- | ---: | :-----
>  26 | a     |    1 | a     
>  31 | b     |    3 | x     
>  32 | c     |    4 | y     
>  33 | d     | null | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=86c7e2323d79dad5fcf7188cef0146b9)*

Comment: Fuck yeah, LukStorms. You're exactly right. I actually came up with the same solution as you did -- and split the original query into two separate ones, one with `WHERE cid = 26` and one with `WHERE cid != 26`. That one change, amazingly, dropped the query time down from 40 minutes to 4 minutes.

Comment: Glad that it worked.  It's probably because the join on pcode is slow, unless it's only for 1 cid.  Using `union all` versus `union` wouldn't have such a huge executiontime/10 impact.